# Vector fields on homogeneous space $G/H$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am trying to understand why the vector fields on $G/H$ are maps $X:G\rightarrow \frak{g}/\frak{h}$ satisfying $X(rh)=Ad^{-1}(h)X(r),\,\, h\in H.$

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you lift a vector field from G/H to G?

Comment: I think part of the problem is to show that the tangent bundle of $M=G/H,$ is $TM=G \times \frak{g}/\frak{h}$ by $(g,x)$ to be equivalent to $(gh^{-1}, Ad_h (x) ).$